# AWS Congito Authentication with JupyterNotebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, jupyterhub

I am trying to authenticate my jupyter notebook with aws cognito by following the steps mention at

http://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/auth/awscognito.html#create-an-aws-cognito-application

however on reloading the configuration , its not working as expected. On making the default changes to authenticate using FirstUseAuthenticator it works fine.

Can some one help me in resolving this issue

Comment: What do you mean with "not working as expected" and with "making the default changes to authenticate using FirstUseAuthenticator"?

Comment: After creating the necessary files and providing the required data , on reloading the tljh-config it fails. The Hub does not get activated and reloaded. However on reverting back to default authentication it works fine and gets reloaded.